# Expected value equal to expected value of expected value squared?

Tags: probability, statistics

I am trying to rederive the canonical expression for variance $V[X] = E[X^2] - E[X]^2$.

What I don't understand is the second line. If you multiply E( ... ) by the last term, wouldn't you get $E(E[X]^2)$? Is $E(E[X]^2) = E[X]^2$ ?

[image]

$E(E[X]^2) = E[X]^2$

Comment: The expected value of the expected value squared is just the expected value squared.  Why?  BEcause the expected value squared is a constant and the expected value of a constant is just that constant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remember that the expected value is a measure of some central tendency, the average.  When discussing the average, we are talking about a particular number, a constant.  From here, we can see that squaring the expected value is just squaring a constant yielding another constant.  Thus if 
$E[X]=\mu$ for some random variable $X$, then $E[X]^2=\mu^2$.  Now what is 
$E[E[X]^2]$

$$E[E[X]^2]=E[\mu^2]=\mu^2=E[X]^2$$

Comment: While this is wholly correct, I think it would be clearer if you did not focus so much on the "squaring".  As you point out, the expected value is a constant.  So, it's expectation is also the same constant.  That is, $E[x] = E[E[x]] = E[E[E[x]]]...$ because only $x$ has a distribution.  The rest are all constants.

Answer (score 1):

Your sequence of equalities is correct. But now, observe that $E[X]$ is a number, right? As it is his square, $E[X]^2$ is again a number, agree?

But what happens when you take the expected value of a number? It is the number itself. You can see a number as a constant random variable, so let $Z \equiv a $, $$E[Z] = aP(Z=a)=a$$

So, $E[E[X]^2]=E[X]^2$