# Expectation of $\bar X^2$

Tags: statistics

If all enumerated $X$s are observations from a population with a population $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$:

Why is this true?

> $$\mathbb E\!\left(\bar X ^2\right) = \frac{\sigma^2}{n}+\mu^2$$

[Source.](http://s0.wp.com/latex.php?latex=%5Cmathbb+E%28%5Cbar%7BX%7D%5E2%29+%3D+%5Cfrac%7B%5Csigma%5E2%7D%7Bn%7D+%2B+%5Cmu%5E2&bg=ffffff&fg=333333&s=0)

Comment: There are many drafting errors in you OP. Moreover, What did you try?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/918804/expected-value-equal-to-expected-value-of-expected-value-squared for some clues.

Comment: Sorry, David and probablyme. I'll keep this in mind for next time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you mean if $X_i$ are iid...

---

As a hint,
recall that 
$$\text{Var}[\bar X] = E[\bar X^2]-\{E[\bar X]\}^2.\tag a$$

Expand and solve 
$$E[\bar X] = E\left[\frac{X_1+\dotsb+X_n}{n}\right] \tag b$$
and
$$
\text{Var}[\bar X]=\text{Var}\left[\frac{X_1+\dotsb+X_n}{n}\right].\tag c$$
Remember to use independence.

Finally, use (b) and (c) to solve (a)
$$E[\bar X^2] = \text{Var}[\bar X]+\{E[\bar X]\}^2.$$

Comment: Ok I see. On the rhs, on the rightmost term, the 1/n comes out by linearity, so there is no multiplier related to n in that term. With regard to the leftmost term on the rhs, 1/n^2 comes out giving us a variance of a sum of iid rvs. Therefore, the variance of the sum is the sum of the variance. Leaving us with true desired value, 1/n^2* n* sigma^2

Comment: @DaBuj Yes, that sounds correct.